# The dynamic link library for GLPK for Java could not be loaded. Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, glpk

I'm currently working on a home-project and I had to use GLPK. I'm working on Eclipse and Windows.

So I've set the java build path properly in my project, did my stuff, everything was working fine, and one day I had some surprise java update, which screwed everything. Now I'm having this message :

```
The dynamic link library for GLPK for Java could not be loaded.
Consider using
java -Djava.library.path=
The current value of system property java.library.path is:
C:\Users\Marks\workspace\TER\librairies\jdom;C:\Users\Marks\workspace\TER\librairies\glpk-4.55\w64
```

And I can't achieve to make my project work again, I've tried everything, loading the DLL with System.load, building with an older GLPK version, trying to compile by myself the glpk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given information it seems everything is setup correctly.

I once had a similar error after a java update where it messed up the 32 bit and 64 bit Versions on my machine (setting 32 bit as default). So the execution of the Source on 32 bit Java requires the dynamic link libraries located in the `glpk-4.55\w32` directory.

Comment: Wow thank you very much mate you just saved my end year project, I'm so thankful you can't know how. To add more information, because of the java Update, I had all the GLPK files into the previous java folder which was used by eclipse, I just had to move theses files into the new JRE folder